# How to restore the previous one workflow in sharepoint designer 2013 ?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have made some changes on my workflow i want to rollback to old one how can i do?
I search it but in 2013 designer under All files -workflows i can't see the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

> A Sharepoint designer workflow? To re-activate an old one, go to the
>   list, settings, workflow settings, you should see the different
>   versions.  Click (strangely enough) Remove a workflow...re-active the
>   old version.
>
> Or, for the source files from sharepoint designer navigate to
>   workflows, find yours, expand it until you find the .aspx and .xml
>   files.  Right-click and choose version history.
>
> Visual studio doesn't do versioning.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a26b692-31ef-41a4-a2c8-baeee62a862d/my-workflow-just-crashed-how-do-you-revert-to-previous-version-sharepoint-designer?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)

Refer also [this](https://wonderlaura.com/2012/05/02/sharepoint-designer-restore-previous-workflow-version/)